# Set up a two-machine-development environment

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, sharepoint, vmware-workstation

I took over a SharePoint developing virtual machines images (VMWare) after a colleague quit.

It is a two machines developer environment, one with SharePoint Server, the other one with SQL.

When I boot up both machines, and I try to go to Central Admin in SharePoint, I got an error that it can't connect to the configuration database.

I try to ping these machines, but they can't reach each other.

Is there an article/guide that shows what is the proper way to set this up?

Which connection should be bridged or NAT? DNS? Gateways?

- Host machine use wireless to connect to Internet.
- Both guest should see each other, and also use the hosts wireless for Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Your possible using VMware Workstation, This possible worked before, so you need to check the guest VM's if they had static or DHCP address. if DHCP then try setup each VM to connect to the NAT vmnet0 network, it's in the vm configuration settings.

in each guest you should also check if the network adapters disabled them selves, (that happens) 
Also if you cloned the VM's or where asked before you booted them, then the MAC address might have changed, hence if they where used in a DHCP configuration, different addresses would be assigned.

Virtual network Editor is under Edit menu, but you shouldn't have to edit that,

- VMware workstation manual is here; (ch5 page 143)
  http://www.vmware.com/pdf/desktop/ws90-using.pdf
- This youtube link will help too
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbgUh16UxKw